# How to give notification to user if the user enter any character except numbers in the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GridView` which is editable and is bound to a database. So the datatype of each column in the GridView is Int in the database. Therefore my `GridView` accepts only integer.

But I want to give a notification to the user if the user enters any other character in the `GridView` cells other than numbers.

Basically I need to validate and give a error message.

Can someone help me how to go about it?

I have used Boundfields for my `GridView`.

Therefore suppose I enter any character other than a number it gives me an exception message saying : **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'a' to data type int.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You best bet is to convert the `BoundField` into a `TemplateField` and add the validation control to the `EditItemTemplate`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Application" SortExpression="APPName">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtApp" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("APPName") %>'/>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat='server' ID='requiredApp' 
            ErrorMessage='Application Name Cannot Be Empty' ControlToValidate='txtApp' /> 
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="labelApp" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("APPName") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1190347/491243)**