# How to validate Grid view in Edit mode using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, gridview

I have a grid view that can edit data, which is bound to an
sqldatasource.

However, there are some text boxes in edit mode which I would like to
validate. For example, one of the is required and cannot be left empty.
How can I make such validation in edit mode in a grid view using javascript?

```
function ValidateGridEditMode()
{
var Grid = document.getElementById('gridview.clientid');

  //how can i get textboxes and apply validation
}
```

Comment: how have you bound your gridview? please show some markup.

Answer (score 1):

Convert those columns into Template columns, and in the ItemTemplate, add a standard Validation control.  Ensure that the EnableClientScript is set to true on the validation control.

There is a similar (but not exact duplicate) post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1190338/validate-a-gridview) that gives a code sample in a valid answer.